# close and open popup with one button in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I am trying to make a *jquery mobile* **popup button** which should perform two functions:

**on first click:** open popup;

**on second click:** close that popup;

I have already made:
 - a dismissible button which programmatically opens a popup;
Here is the **code** that I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/MKHnS/

JS:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#zozo', function () {       
         $('#zozo-list').popup();        
         $('#zozo-list').popup('open');

         })
```

Now I need to:
 - make **second** function : next click on same button should close the popup;

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated...

Comment: Use jQuery toggle(). http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: You can't, with `data-dismissible=false` any click outside popup will be neglected. Setting to `true` will close popup immediately if clicked outside popup.

Comment: Thanks @SuryaS for suggestion, I am quite new in jquery and don't understand it very well.  I've tried **toggle()**, but still have some issues: popup appears only after two clicks and overlayTheme is still there. Maybe i'm not using toggle() properly?! here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/64RGw/

Comment: Hi, @Omar I gave higher z-index to the button and it is not dismissible during popup, it is stil clickable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the popup is whether open, accordingly, `.popup("open")` or `.popup("close")`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#zozo', function () {
    if ($(".ui-popup-active").length > 0) {
        $('#zozo-list').popup('close');
    } else {
        $('#zozo-list').popup('open');
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Lf4XD/)**